# SQL select first value in a row then insert that value into another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008

I'm not very good with sql so I'm not sure if this is possible.  Or maybe even in excel??  I'm trying to select the very first value and ignore duplicates from Product_ID and then add that first value for that row to the Title column.

Also note that my product list is over 25,000+ items.

So take this:

```
+---------------+------------+-------+-------------+-------+
| Product_Count | Product_ID | Title | _Color_Name | _Size |
+---------------+------------+-------+-------------+-------+
| 2             | 14589      |       | Black       | 00    |
| 3             | 14589      |       | Black       | 0     |
| 4             | 14589      |       | Black       | 2     |
| 5             | 14589      |       | Black       | 4     |
| 6             | 14589      |       | Black       | 6     |
| 11            | 14589      |       | Dark Coral  | 00    |
| 12            | 14589      |       | Dark Coral  | 0     |
| 13            | 14589      |       | Dark Coral  | 2     |
| 14            | 14589      |       | Dark Coral  | 4     |
| 15            | 14589      |       | Dark Coral  | 6     |
| 129           | 15027      |       | Aqua        | 00    |
| 130           | 15027      |       | Aqua        | 0     |
| 131           | 15027      |       | Aqua        | 2     |
| 132           | 15027      |       | Aqua        | 4     |
| 133           | 15027      |       | Aqua        | 6     |
| 138           | 15027      |       | Black       | 00    |
| 139           | 15027      |       | Black       | 0     |
| 140           | 15027      |       | Black       | 2     |
| 141           | 15027      |       | Black       | 4     |
| 142           | 15027      |       | Black       | 6     |
+---------------+------------+-------+-------------+-------+
```

And turn it into this:

```
+---------------+------------+-------+-------------+-------+
| Product_Count | Product_ID | Title | _Color_Name | _Size |
+---------------+------------+-------+-------------+-------+
| 2             | 14589      | 14589 | Black       | 00    |
| 3             | 14589      |       | Black       | 0     |
| 4             | 14589      |       | Black       | 2     |
| 5             | 14589      |       | Black       | 4     |
| 6             | 14589      |       | Black       | 6     |
| 11            | 14589      |       | Dark Coral  | 00    |
| 12            | 14589      |       | Dark Coral  | 0     |
| 13            | 14589      |       | Dark Coral  | 2     |
| 14            | 14589      |       | Dark Coral  | 4     |
| 15            | 14589      |       | Dark Coral  | 6     |
| 129           | 15027      | 15027 | Aqua        | 00    |
| 130           | 15027      |       | Aqua        | 0     |
| 131           | 15027      |       | Aqua        | 2     |
| 132           | 15027      |       | Aqua        | 4     |
| 133           | 15027      |       | Aqua        | 6     |
| 138           | 15027      |       | Black       | 00    |
| 139           | 15027      |       | Black       | 0     |
| 140           | 15027      |       | Black       | 2     |
| 141           | 15027      |       | Black       | 4     |
| 142           | 15027      |       | Black       | 6     |
+---------------+------------+-------+-------------+-------+
```

Comment: ugh..why did my table look like that.. :(

Comment: you should create the table like that. need to CREATE TABLE recentDetails"
                    + "(_id integer primary key autoincrement,"
                    + "fileName TEXT, filePath TEXT UNIQUE ,fileSize TEXT,fileDate TEXT);

Comment: Um - Is this MySql or Sql-Server? I've assumed Sql-Server in my answer OFC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `PARTITION` to window the `ProductIds` and then identify the first row in each partition with [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
SELECT 
  ProductID, 
  Product_Count, 
  CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN ProductID else null END AS Title, 
  Color_Name, 
  Size
FROM
(
    SELECT ProductID, Product_Count, Color_Name, Size,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductID ORDER BY Product_Count) AS rn
    FROM product_stock
) AS X;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4d9e2/1)

Comment: Not sure how to Partition it.  But I have like over 50,000 products in my tables.  So that's just not practical.

Comment: I mean the windowing function `PARTITION BY`, not a table partitioning function :) Try the fiddle and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
Declare @t table (col1 int,col2 int,col3 int)
insert into @t values(2,3,null),(2,4,null),(5,3,null),(5,4,null)

;with CTE as
(select *,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by col1 order by col1)rn from @t

)

select a.col1,a.col2,case when a.rn=1 then b.col1 end col3 from CTE a
left join (select col1 from cte where rn>1) b on a.col1=b.col1
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the table with UNIQUE.

```
CREATE TABLE recentDetails"
                    + "(_id integer primary key autoincrement,"
                    + "fileName TEXT, filePath TEXT UNIQUE ,fileSize TEXT,fileDate TEXT);
```

Comment: I still need the duplicates as it's listed, but I just need to identify and copy that first value from product_ID into the Title column, so that I can import it.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * from TABLE_NAME WHERE Product_count IN (SELECT MIN(Product_COUNT) 
FROM TABLE_NAME
where Product_ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT Product_ID FROM TABLE_NAME)) AND Product_ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT Product_ID FROM TABLE_NAME)`

Comment: getting this error:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '('.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '('.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: I have corrected it instead of IS there should be IN which I have modified